# Can't retrieve attribute value from an XML element in jquery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have xml that looks like this:

```
<marker>
        <name>Ada County Jail</name>
        <adr>Boise</adr>
        <state>Idaho</state>
        <geo>43.6073458, -116.2698884</geo>
        <tag>County</tag>
        <ice>t</ice>
        <url title="Ada County Jail">https://adacounty.id.gov/sheriff/ada-county-jail/</url>
        <url title="Inmates">https://apps.adacounty.id.gov/sheriff/reports/inmates.aspx</url>
</marker>
```

I'm using jquery. I pull out the URL elements here:

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function()
        {
         var url = $(this).find('url').map(function(i,v){return ($(v).text());}).get();
...
```

I'm trying to extract the text of the title attributes of the url elements so the HTML links look like this:

```
Link: Ada County Jail
Link: Inmates
```

This code fails with an unrecognized expression message:

```
for (i=0;i<url.length;i++){
      var web = url[i];
      var y = $(xml).find(url[1]).attr("title");
      html += '<a href="' + web + '">Link: ' + y + '</a>';
      }
```

This is my first time trying to access attributes. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the `title` attribute from the `url` elements you can modify your code like so:

```
$xml.find("marker").each(function() {
  $(this).find('url').each(function() {
    const url = $(this).text();
    const title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#links').append(`<a href="${url}">Link: ${title}</a><br>`);
  });
});
```

Here's a working example you can run on your machine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>XML Parsing Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="links"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const xmlString = `
        <marker>
          <name>Ada County Jail</name>
          <adr>Boise</adr>
          <state>Idaho</state>
          <geo>43.6073458, -116.2698884</geo>
          <tag>County</tag>
          <ice>t</ice>
          <url title="Ada County Jail">https://adacounty.id.gov/sheriff/ada-county-jail/</url>
          <url title="Inmates">https://apps.adacounty.id.gov/sheriff/reports/inmates.aspx</url>
        </marker>
      `;

      const xml = $.parseXML(xmlString);
      const $xml = $(xml);

      $xml.find("marker").each(function() {
        $(this).find('url').each(function() {
          const url = $(this).text();
          const title = $(this).attr('title');
          $('#links').append(`<a href="${url}">Link: ${title}</a><br>`);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If this doesn't fix your issue, or if anything is unclear, let me know in  a comment and I'll revise my answer.